# drillthrough month and year grouping error

Tags: reporting-services

I used the query below to create a parameter for a drillthrough in my ssrs.

SELECT DISTINCT month([OrderDate])AS 'Month', 
FROM cob_adhoc
where datepart(MONTH,[OrderDate])  = @month
group by year([OrderDate]), month([OrderDate])

in my report, i have columns for year and month and other data. The month column has the textbox action to lead to the selected month in another table.

My problem is say someone clicks June in 2014, it brings out data from june from all the years on the table and not the year in the report column.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a calculated field in your dataset with the combined values of

```
CalcMonthYear=CSTR(Fields!Month.Value) + CSTR(Fields!Year.Value)
```

Then in you label's action don't go to `[Month]` instead go to `[CalcMonthYear]`